# Load a certain functions file for a certain taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have split up all my functions into separate files and load these from the functions.php using the below:

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/bhh-functions/scripts-styles.php';
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/bhh-functions/user-functions.php';
```

However, I now have a functions file that I only want to load on a certain taxonomy page. I have tried the following and other possibilities with no luck.

```
if (has_term('16', 'product_cat', )) {
  require get_template_directory() . '/inc/bhh-functions/tax-functions.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's three things going on with your code.

The first is that you're passing a numeric string as the first parameter to `has_term()`. If you're trying to pass the term ID to the function, you should remove the quotes from '16' and just pass 16, i.e. as integer.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/

The second is that you're using `has_term()` to *load on a certain taxonomy page*. That function is for checking if a post has certain term, not if the query is for a taxonomy page. You should use `is_tax( $taxonomy, $term)` instead.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/

The third thing is that you're doing the conditional check directly on the functions.php file. Due to loading and actions firing order, the check happens too early. Wrap the check in a callback function and attach that for example to `template_redirect` action hook. By the time that action happens WP has set up itself proprely and the conditional function has the necessary data to check against.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'bhh_single_product_functions', 10);

function bhh_single_product_functions()
{
    if (has_term(16, 'product_cat',)) {
        require get_template_directory() . '/inc/bhh-functions/single-product-category-x.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is your final code based on Antti's answer?

Comment: I'd make it `require_once` just in case something else ends up loading this too. (But I guess this is your own theme?)